# If a point is a not isolated singularity for a complex function, is it then always an essential singularity?

Tags: complex-analysis

If a point is a not isolated singularity for a complex function, is it then always an essential singularity? If not, can you give me a counterexample?
I know the opposite implication is not true and a counterexample is $z=0$ for $\sin(\frac{1}{z})$, which is an essential singularity, but an isolated one.

Comment: I think you are mixing up notions in your question. Every singularity of a holomorphic function on $\mathbb C$ is isolated, i.e. a point.

Comment: What is your definition of essential singularity? Usually it contains isolated - 0 is a branch singularity of the logarithm (non-isolated as you need to cut out a ray to make the logarithm analytic or even continuous) and the logarithm goes to infinity there like at a pole though here the real part actually goes to minus infinity, while the imaginary part stays bounded

Comment: I was taught that an essential singularity is isolated, and that  $z=0$ is a *branch point* of $\log{z}$

Comment: by "$f$ has an essential singularity at $z=z_0$" I mean that the Laurent series of $f$, centered at $z=z_0$, has infinitely many powers with negative exponent.

Comment: If $z_0$ is not isolated, what Laurent series do you mean?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I mean the Laurent series that converges on an annulus that lays between the singularities that surround $z_0$ or an annulus outside the region where the singularities concentrate.

Comment: There might not even be such an annulus.

Comment: What about $f=\frac{1}{sin(\frac{\pi}{z})}$? I read in another question that it does not have a Laurent Expansion at $z=0$, but I don't understand why: in my course notes the Laurent Theorem states that if $f$ is holomorphic on the annulus $r<|z-z_0|<R$, then $f$ admits a Laurent series centered at $z_0$ that converges uniformly to the function on $r<|z-z_0|<R$. $\frac{1}{sin(\frac{\pi}{z})}$ is holomorphic for example on the annulus $1/2<|z|<1$. Why can't I write the Laurent series centered in $z=0$ and converging in $1/2<|z|<1$? It seems to me it satisfies the theorem's hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

No: an essential singularity is by definition isolated.  A non-isolated singularity is just that, a non-isolated singularity.

EDIT: Suppose $f$ has a Laurent series that converges in an annulus $r_1 < |z - z_0| < r_2$, and has only finitely many nonzero terms with negative exponent.
The sum of those terms with negative exponent is a rational function whose only pole is at $z_0$, while the terms with positive exponent converge to an analytic function in $|z-z_0| < r_2$.  Thus we can analytically continue $f$ to a function that has a pole at $z_0$ and no other singularities in $|z - z_0| < r_2$.